# Django: Save user uploads in seperate folders

Tags: python, django, upload, models

I want individual users to be able to upload their files into a single folder (so each user has their own root folder, where they can upload their own files), but I am not sure of the best way to go about implementing this.

I originally planned to use the users email as the their folder name, and all their uploads would be saved in this folder. However, from what I have gathered the only way of retrieving this information is through the request function, and I cannot manage to get an instance of request into the models.py file, and therefore cannot add it to my 'upload_to' directory.

Any other ideas of how to separate users files, or how to get an instance of request in the models file would be greatly appreciated!!

Here is my current model:

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)

class UploadModel(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

And it's associated error:

```
Exception Value: UploadModel has no user.
```

Answer (score 12):

1. I don't recommend you to use user email or any other information that can be updated as folder name because you won't change folder name each time he changes his email or his username. So, use user id that is unique and unchangeable.
2. Here is a complete example from Django documentation, to access instance information in your models to build path with user id :

```python
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)

class MyModel(models.Model):
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

In this case, it use the user id in the folder name. Of course, your can replace`FileField` with `ImageField`.

More information in django docs : [FileFields.upload_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to)

Comment: 1. Ah good point, I'll use user id then.
2. I had come across this but received an error and forgot about it. But now I have applied it again, however I still receive the same error:  " 'UploadModel' object has no attribute 'user' " where 'UploadModel' is the model which contains my FileField

Comment: I gave you an example, add all related models if you want that I give you a concrete example. `instance` represent the current object, if your model is your user model, then use `instance.id`. `instance.user.id` is used when the current model have a `OneToOneField` to the default user model relationship.

Comment: Okay, would adding " user = models.OneToOneField(User) " be correct? Because this threw an error ('UploadModel' has no user), so I feel like I'm missing something. Sorry, I'm new to Django, so please excuse the novice questions.

Comment: add your model in your question and precise Error please

Comment: did you make migrations and migrate?

Comment: Yes, I did. I have however had success sending an instance of the user from the view to the model.

Comment: @LouisBarranqueiro In your models class where `upload_to=user_directory_path` why are you just giving function name? I wondering `user_directory_path` function should be call 
 inside views.py file..

Answer (score 5):

You could maybe separate the folder by their username? You can create a function that would create a folder using the users username like so:

```
def get_user_image_folder(instance, filename):
    return "%s/%s" %(instance.user.username, filename)
```

and in your model you could easily use the `upload_to` and add the function that you just created to it:

```
class Images(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User)
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_user_image_folder,
                                  verbose_name='Image', )
```

You don't have to use `request` in Models, you use `instance` instead.

Comment: Hi there, I have applied this, but I get the error: "Exception Value: UploadModel has no user", as added to my question.

Comment: Oh, when I don't use the user variable, I then get the error: "table Core_uploadmodel has no column named user_id", not sure where to go with this.

Comment: I updated my answer @Kane, I think you need to add a user field in the UploadModel as a FK. Try that out, and don't forget to migrate to update your databse.

Answer (score 2):

To get this to work I implemented the solution from the docs as suggested by Louis Barranqueiro, whereby the models looks like:

```
# models.py
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)

class Document(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='documents')
```

But crucially, I also changed my DocumentUploadView class to include a save step, so that the document saves with the user attribute (note also the initial commit=False save step, which is crucial):

```
# views.py
class DocumentUploadView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        documents_list = Document.objects.all()
        return render(self.request, 'file_upload.html', {'documents': documents_list})

    def post(self, request):
        form = DocumentForm(self.request.POST, self.request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            document = form.save(commit=False)
            document.user = request.user
            document.save()
            data = {'is_valid': True, 'name': document.file.name, 'url': document.file.url}
        else:
            data = {'is_valid': False}
        return JsonResponse(data)
```

Finally my forms.py looks like this:

```
# forms.py
class DocumentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
    fields = ('file',)
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else in the future that stumble across this, I got access to the current user's ID by adding the user object to the model in the view.

views.py

```
from .models import Document

if request.method == 'POST':
    form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        newdoc = Document(docfile=request.FILES['docfile'])
        newdoc.owner = request.user
        newdoc.save()
```

Then, in models.py you can retrieve the ID from owner created previously in view.

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    return 'Users/user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.owner.id, filename)


class Document(models.Model):
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your views.py you must pass the instance argument like this:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if 'uploadFile' in request.POST:
        f = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=request.user.uploadmodel)
        if f.is_valid():
            f.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/sucess_url')
```

And your forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import UploadForm


class UploadFileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UploadForm
        fields = ('file',)
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem. Here is how I solved it. We have to create the user referencing in the view.

Below is the code for **models.py**

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return 'user_{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.id, filename)

class Document(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    docfile = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

Also update the code in views.py as below:

```
def upload(request):
    # Handle file upload
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            newdoc = Document(docfile=request.FILES['docfile'],user=request.user)
            newdoc.save()
            latest_documents = Document.objects.all().order_by('-id')[0]

            # Redirect to the document list after POST
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('list'))
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()  # A empty, unbound form

    # Load documents for the list page
    documents = Document.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

The most important one is in the line,

```
newdoc = Document(docfile=request.FILES['docfile'],user=request.user)
```

Somehow I could not get the model instance to read the user. This approach is working for me.